# Lost WiFi - How To Enable wlan0 on Rasbian Pi 3b+?

Tags: raspberry-pi, wifi-configuration, raspbian

On my WiFi indicator on my taskbar which used to work well, it now has two red x's. When I hover over it I get the message WLAN0 stopped working. I have read a bunch of solutions, none of which seem to match my circumstances. I had been working through VCN from my Windows 10 PC and the Pi started to lose connections. After a few reconnects the Pi screen went black. I was forced to do a cold re-start and it booted but then I got the dreaded red x's. Can someone walk me through troubleshooting step by step? I did see that the Country was blank in the preferences and I set that to USA but that did not help. Thanks in advance! I am a newbie to Linux Raspian and the Pi 3b+. Neat little machine but it sure seems fragile!

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!  I read this article and while the circumstances were different I was out of good solutions other than re-flashing my card and wasting many days of solid development efforts.
[url]https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=277374

What I did was to follow the steps for changing monitor resolution.  With a difference.  Mine was set to sense what the monitor wanted for best resolution.  I re-set it to that, then rebooted.  After it re-booted my WiFi magically re-appeared!  I don't know why monitor resolution would interfere with sensing WiFi networks but it did and it is working now.